# How to call captureStream method of HTMLVideoElement in React

Tags: html, reactjs, html5-video, capturestream

I am trying to generate video stream to pass it to `navigator.getUserMedia` call back function. basically trying to mock `getUserMedia` for react test.
For Above i am creating video element , setting it src and then calling `captureStream()` for stream.

see code below

```js
const video = document.createElement('video');
video.autoplay = true
video.loop = true
video.src = 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4';
video.load()
video.play()
const stream = video.captureStream();
```

this code working in js file , i am getting my stream but in react project, its throws `TypeError :captureStram() not a function`.

Edit: I tried using ref but still it's not working.

Comment: This is React -- do NOT use document (DOM) to create element. instead used the element using the useRef() hook

Comment: still if this is utmost required for you to manipulate the DOM, render the DOM element using 'react-dom' NPM package and then fiddle it with.